# A way to check if html changed in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a JS code which should do some things (animations etc.) BEFORE ReactJS possibly (or not) will update HTML element. I'm getting the whole template for this HTML element (i.e. part of the page, in particular a widget) for this purpose.

For example, I have a DIV with some content, which may change in time or not. Then I get a new version (i.e. as HTML template) of that DIV through AJAX call, and I want ReactJS first to **compare the actual (or virtual) current DOM with the one just retrieved new HTML template for the same DIV in a string** as got from AJAX call on success. Only then - when these two are different - it makes sense to do animations first, and only then update the actual DOM in the browser by React JS.

How to do that? Is there a method in React JS that allows me to get e.g. true/false when comparing virtual DOM with its new version as a HTML template got through AJAX (since it does internally this thing anyway - i.e. comparing current and updated DOM in its algorithm)?

**EDIT**: Hmm after initial thought that ReactJS is way much better than other JS Frameworks in my case (i.e. server functionality is already developed), I found multiple features not flexible enough; further more, I found ReactJS is not smart enough to figure out that only one element at the top of the list is added (ReactJS replaces the whole DOM template for the list, even with keys set for each element!), which suggests it's still not that mature as one could expect.
Besides, all Lifecycle methods with ***Component***Update are not called; only ***Component***Unmount are being called in the case of mentioned list. I can do it in a simpler way by myself, however Relay / Flux + ReactJS architecture is still nice, and I think I'll just abandon Facebook's implementation, and replace it with my own solution, inspired by Relay/Flux+ReactJS.

Comment: could u show us some code? a fiddle, it will be alot easier to see what is going on.

Comment: @danillo2k It's just that I was unable to explain it clearly, but it's really very simple and common to most Ajax apps: its just refreshing a HTML component - as updated from the server (through an Ajax call), i.e. dynamically replacing e.g. DIV with new one. The idea is how to deal with React JS with it, as it gives some extra complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the following life cycle methods:

```
componentWillUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState)
componentDidUpdate(object prevProps, object prevState)
```

From the react docs:

**componentWillUpdate**

*Invoked immediately before rendering when new props or state are being received. This method is not called for the initial render.
Use this as an opportunity to perform preparation before an update occurs.*

**componentDidUpdate**

*Invoked immediately after the component's updates are flushed to the DOM. This method is not called for the initial render.
Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated.*